# Failing to subset the right rows based on the rank passed through the num argument of rankall function

Tags: r

This is a coursework I had for R programming on Coursera. I've completed this course, but I really want to get to the bottom of the errors in my code.

The relevant fields of this data set contains Hospitals, States, and three mortality measures. A function `rankall(outcome, num = "best")` needs to be created to return a data frame showing hospital in each state based on the rank passed through `num` argument and mortality measure passed through outcome.

When `num` was a numeric value, my script worked correctly. However, when `num` was either "best" or "worst", incorrect hospitals were returned.

When calling `tail(rankall("pneumonia", "worst"), 3)`, the expected value returned should be the following:

```
                                 hospital state
WI MAYO CLINIC HEALTH SYSTEM - NORTHLAND, INC    WI

WV                     PLATEAU MEDICAL CENTER    WV

WY           NORTH BIG HORN HOSPITAL DISTRICT    WY
```

The returned value I got is below:

```
                                state
WI "HOLY FAMILY MEMORIAL INC"   "WI" 

WV "THOMAS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL"   "WV" 

WY "SHERIDAN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL" "WY"
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who is willing to spare time reading my post.

Here is my script:

```
rankall <- function (outcome, num = "best") {

dat <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClass = "character", na.strings = "Not Available")

#verify outcome
if (!outcome %in% c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")){
    stop("invalid outcome")
}

#verify num
if (!is.numeric(num)) {
    if (is.character(num)) {
        if (!num %in% c("best", "worst")){
            stop("invalid num")
        }
    }
}

col = c("heart attack" = 11, "heart failure" = 17, "pneumonia" = 23)
state = unique(dat$State)
state = state[order(state)]

subdat <- dat[,c(2,7,col)]
names(subdat) <- c("hospital", "state", "death")
subdat$death <- as.numeric(subdat$death)
subdat$hospital <- as.character(subdat$hospital)
subdat <- subdat[complete.cases(subdat$death),]

s = split(subdat, subdat$state)
ls_hospital <- lapply(s, function(x, num) {
    x <- x[order(x$death, x$hospital, na.last = NA),]
    if (num == "best") {return(x$hospital[1])}
    else if (num == "worst") {return(x$hospital[nrow(x)])}
    else {return(x$hospital[num])}
}, num)

ans <- cbind(unlist(ls_hospital), state)
return(ans)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one error. When you are subsetting the original
dataframe your code is:

```
subdat <- dat[,c(2,7,col)]
```

This is taking State, Hospital Name and all the fields specified in *col*.
Basically no mortality measure selection takes place.
The correct code is:

```
subdat <- dat[,c(2,7,col[outcome])]
```

In this way the correct mortality measure is selected and the rest of the
code works as expected.

Comment: OMG, that's really a very stupid mistake. Thank you so much for your help, thepule!